# Django ORM, latest items/messages by groups/folders

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am using Django 1.8, i have some model:

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField( max_length=255 )

class Message(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField( max_length=255 )
    folder = models.ForeignKey( Folder )
```

I need, screen with display all Folders with latest Messages with limit (like 10), like:

```
F1:    F2:   F3:
 m1     m3    m6
 m2     m4    ..
 m3     m5    ..
              m10
```

How i can create this query with django-orm ? Thank.

Comment: How do you define `latest` here? Do you have a `DateTimeField` as well?

Comment: For simplification by message id

Comment: @DmitriyYusupov message id is not a date.

Comment: ok, latest by id with auto increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `property` in your `Folder` model:

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField( max_length=255 )

    @property
    def latest_10_messages(self):
        # order by id decreasing and get top 10
        return self.message_set.order_by('-id')[:10]
```

And, then in your template you could use it:

```
{% for folder in folders %}
    {{ folder.name }}

    {% for msg in folder.latest_10_messages %}
        {{ msg.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

**UPDATE** to reduce the number of queries to the database:

If you want to reduce the number of queries you could use [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object with custom queryset:

```
prefetch_query = Prefetch('message_set__title', queryset=Message.objects.all().order_by('-id'), to_attr='message_titles')
folders = Folder.objects.all().prefetch_related(prefetch_query)
```

and then in the template use `slice` to get top 10:

```
{% for folder in folders %}
    {{ folder.name }}

    {% for msg in folder.message_titles|slice":10" %}
        {{ msg }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. Good. But if i have many folders this solution created many query in database.  But I want to do in the 1-2 query.

Comment: You want 10 messages for each folder right? and you want to show the title as well?

Comment: Yes, Panel looks like this: https://hsto.org/files/4d9/7ed/f13/4d97edf13d1041b2821c9d2f502bab12.png

Comment: Good, this solution looked like what we need. Thank you. After testing i am replying again. 
But I do not know, because at the database level limit no limit, I do not know how it would work if the messages in the folder will be tens of thousands

Comment: Hello, Thank you again. Second solution more slower that first. Now i'm using first. ( in 20000 items, first solution worked 1.5 seconds, first: 57 ms

Comment: @DmitriyYusupov Happy to help! Please accept the best answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

To get a better performance you could try using [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
# get the folders
folders = Folder.objects.all().prefetch_related('message_set')

# create a result list
result = []

# populate result list
result = [{'folder': f.title, 'messages': f.message_set.values('title').order_by('-id')[:10]} for f in folders]

# every f.message_set... won't hit database, because of prefetch_related
```

Then in your template:

```
<ul>
  {% for res in result %}
    <li>
      {% for message in res.messages %}
        {{ message.title }}
      {% endfor %}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Or you can take a look over [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) in template.

**Disclaimer**: This code was tested with a similar models structure and not in template, so, maybe you will need to make some little changes. to fit your needs.

Comment: @Gocht you are not ordering the messages but the OP want latest 10.

Comment: @AKS You are right, I added the order and filter. As I said, some little changes will be needed.